# What is this row of sandy material in my wall?

Tags: drywall, mold, termite

I am enclosing an outdoor alcove 120”x 70” and notice brown residue where the studs and drywall meet together- this is on several areas of the room and walls but there does not appear to be any damage to any of the wood.

I live in Northern California

If I touch it it easily falls off

[image]

Comment: I'm no expert but that looks like insect scat to me.

Comment: ... and feeding damage to the drywall surface.

Answer (score 3):

Classic, typical termite tunnel. Brush and scrape it away and if you don't see live termites inside, then you don't have to do anything. Follow the tunnel up from the earth and down to see if there is any damage to drywall or structural members. Be careful in probing that you don't damage a water pipe, a drain pipe, or an electrical cable.

Answer (score 2):

looks like termite tunnel. easy to check, just break a bit and see.

Comment: It just falls away like sand or dirt. House was built in 1969, could this be old and not a worry now???

Comment: @Kris I doubt the age of the home matters much. Hard to say when the  termites moved in/out. House could have been treated prior to you and this is just residual. I'd tackle like they are still there.